# Comparing file checksums in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, checksum

I'm writing a file upload site, and am interested in saving space. If a user uploads a file, I want to ensure this file has not already been uploaded before (if it has been, I will just point to the existing file in the database).

I was considering using `sha1_file()` on the file, checking the database to see if the digest exists in a database of digests. Then I remembered the pigeonhole principle, and decided to check the undigested files against each other if there is a sha1 digest match.

This seems inefficient to me. I figure I could just check the first kilobyte of each file against each other in the event of a check sum match.

I haven't thought too much about the value of RAM versus ROM, and it might be possible that the processing power required to check the files costs more than the storage space I would save.

Are there any shortcomings to this method? Am I wasting my time in even bothering with this?

Comment: "Am I wasting my time in even bothering with this?" - it depends upon the costs/benefits ratio. But academically this problem seems interesting.

Comment: "Then I remembered the pigeonhole principle, and decided to check the undigested files against each other if there is a sha1 digest match." - can you explain it better. I don't understand what you mean. You are not using a database of hashes and just compare the files every time?

Comment: If the files are similar, their size must equal. Every filesystem can give you the size of a file, it's an inexpensive operation. Find the files with the same size and then compare the hashes.

Comment: Pigeonhole principle pertains to collisions. If I have two files of size 32kB and a hash algorithm that generates 64B outputs, there's a higher chance of collision than if my output were to be 512B.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `md5( file_data )` to generate the names of the files and it will never be possible to upload the same file with a different name. only problem with this is that it could be technically possible that two different files generate the same md5, but its unlikely, especially if the two files have the same extension, so you could consider this a non problem. under this schematic, there is no reason to even check. if two hashes are the same, it simply overwrites the stored file. this is how most file storage engines work internally, such as [zimg](http://zimg.buaa.us/). if you are paranoid about collisions, you could see first if the file exists with the computed hash and extension, and if it does you could compare the data of that stored file vs the data of the file that you are attempting to store. if the data is inequal, you could have it email you an alert.

```
$data = file_get_contents('flowers.jpg');

$name = md5($data).'.jpg';

$fh = fopen($name,'w+');

fwrite($fh,$data);

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I could probably use a combination of checking the file size, checking a digest of the entire file, then checking the file itself in the event of a collision.

Comment: Just thought of something - Facebook uses multiple digests for image names. I'm guessing one is user ID, but it made me realize that even though one hash algorithm might collide, another might not. If paranoid about collisions, you could digest the file with a quick checksum like CRC and then digest the raw data again using a more computationally intense one; finally, you would concatenate the digests, and save the file as this.